# Add role to alert message that is generated by data-parsley-required-message

Tags: javascript, html, jsp, parsley.js, parsley

I am trying to add a role to the required message generated from data-parsley-required-message, but do not have an idea how to do that.

This element is auto-generated when validating the required field with data-parsley:

```
<ul class="parsley-errors-list filled" id="parsley-id-5485">
<li class="parsley-required">This value is required.</li></ul>
```

I want to add attribute role="alert" as:

`<li class="parsley-required" role="alert"> This value is required.</li>`

Need to add a role to the data-parsley-required-message. How?

Comment: <ul class="parsley-errors-list filled" id="parsley-id-5485">
<li class="parsley-required">This value is required.</li></ul>                                I want to add attribute role="alert" as:
<li class="parsley-required" role="alert">This value is required.</li>

Comment: <textarea id="com" name="com" data-parsley-required-message="This field is required" data-parsley-required=""></textarea> generates -                                                                                   
<ul class="parsley-errors-list filled" id="parsley-id-3667"><li class="parsley-required">This field is required</li></ul> Instead I want the result as:   <li class="parsley-required" role="alert">

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to change the [default values of `errorTemplate` or `errorWrapper`](https://github.com/guillaumepotier/Parsley.js/blob/master/src/parsley/defaults.js#L60..L63). Looks like they are not documented though, but they should. Care to provide a PR?

Comment: <textarea id="com" name="com" data-parsley-required-message="This field is required" data-parsley-required=""></textarea> generates -                                                                                   
<ul class="parsley-errors-list filled" id="parsley-id-3667"><li class="parsley-required">This field is required</li></ul> Instead I want the result as:   <li class="parsley-required" role="alert">

Comment: Yes. I answered your question.